# Sqlite C interface get single value result

Tags: c, sqlite

When I type into Sqlite

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM tabl;
```

it returns a number.

How do I use the C interface to obtain this number after preparing a statement?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Have you checked out the quick start example?
http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

Comment: @iX3: The quickstart is good, but the Select query is a little different. You have to fetch the rows and this is a process, not a single shot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the database file, prepare the statement, make steps (i.e., if you have more than one row in results you have to fetch them one by one), extract column values, finalize the statement, close the database.

Something like this:

```
sqlite3_stmt* stmt = NULL;

sqlite3* local_db = NULL;

sqlite3_open("filename.sqlite", &local_db);

int retval, idx;
char sql[2048];

sprintf(sql, "select Something from Somewhere;");

// execute statement
retval = sqlite3_prepare_v2(local_db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

if(retval)
{
    printf("Selecting data from DB Failed (err_code=%d)\n", retval);
    return;
}

// iterate rows
idx = 0;

// for multiple results
while(1)
{
    // fetch a row's status
    retval = sqlite3_step(stmt);

    if(retval == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        Something =
             (int)sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
             // or other type - sqlite3_column_text etc.
        // ... fetch other columns, if there are any
    }
    else if(retval == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        printf("Some error encountered\n");
        break;
    }
}

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

sqlite3_close(local_db);
```

Use this code, look for all the API calls (open, prepare_v2, step, column, finalize).

If this is hard, then at first you should become familiar with C itself.

Comment: Thanks!. I just used the first result from the first row for the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted, got from [here](https://zetcode.com/db/sqlitec/)

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    
    sqlite3 *db;
    char *err_msg = 0;
    sqlite3_stmt *res;
    
    int rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
    
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        sqlite3_close(db);
        
        return 1;
    }
    
    char *sql = "SELECT Id, Name FROM Cars WHERE Id = @id";
        
    rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);
    
    if (rc == SQLITE_OK) {
        
        int idx = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(res, "@id");
        int value = 4;
        sqlite3_bind_int(res, idx, value);
        
    } else {
        
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute statement: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }
    
    int step = sqlite3_step(res);
    
    if (step == SQLITE_ROW) {
        
        printf("%s: ", sqlite3_column_text(res, 0));
        printf("%s\n", sqlite3_column_text(res, 1));
        
    } 

    sqlite3_finalize(res);
    sqlite3_close(db);
    
    return 0;
}
```