# Creating a function that searches within a SQLite database using the genie programming language

Tags: sqlite, genie

I am trying to do a small program that searches a specific entry within a SQLite database using the Genie programing language. However I am stuck in a point where the prepared statement is not selecting the proper entry. I suppose there is something wrong about the syntax of the statement.

First, here is the search function:

```
def SearchForRecipe (db:Database)
    print "-------------------------------"
    print " Search in"
    print "-------------------------------"
    print " 1 - Recipe Name"
    print " 2 - Recipe Source"
    print " 3 - Ingredients"
    print " 4 - Exit"
    searchin:string = UserInterface.raw_input("Enter Search Type -> ")
    search:string = " "
    sql:string = " "
    response:string=" "
    if searchin != "4"
        if searchin == "1"
            search = "Recipe Name"
        else if searchin is "2"
            search = "Recipe Source"
        else if searchin is "3"
            search = "Ingredients"
        else
            print "An Error Occured"
            print "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            Process.exit (-1)

        parm:string = searchin
        response = UserInterface.raw_input ("Search for what in "+ search +" (blank to exit) -> ")

        if parm == "1" // Recipe Name
            stmt:Statement = PreparedStatements.select_recipe(db, response)
            var row = new dict of string, string
            cols:int = stmt.column_count ()

            print cols.to_string()

            for i:int = 0 to (cols - 1)
                row[ stmt.column_name( i ) ] = stmt.column_text( i )
            stdout.printf( "%-30s", row[ "name" ])
            stdout.printf( "%-20s", row[ "servings" ])
            stdout.printf( "%-30s\n", row[ "source" ])
```

The problem is happening in the if loop: `if parm == "1" // Recipe Name` and in the following line when I ask to print the number of columns of the selected entry it returns me zero. I added that line in order to try to troubleshoot what was going on, but it might not be the best approach to it.

The prepared statement is within a namespace, here is how it looks like:

```
namespace PreparedStatements
    def select_recipe (db:Database, res:string) : Statement
        statement:Statement
        db.prepare_v2( "SELECT pkid,name,source,servings FROM Recipes WHERE name like" + res, -1, out statement)
        return statement
```

I suppose there is something wrong with the SELECT statement in the select_recipe function, because it is not picking the proper entry in the database.

Question: How to select the entry properly? Should I use another approach, or a prepared statement is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `LIKE` then you need to delimit the text in double quotes and if the text could be a substring then you also need to delimit the text between `%` symbols:

```
db.prepare_v2( "SELECT pkid,name,source,servings FROM Recipes WHERE name like \"%" + res + "%\"", -1, out statement)
```

The back slash, `\`, "escapes" the double quote so it is not read as the end of the text. Try the difference between:

```
print "my "test""
```

and

```
print "my \"test\""
```

If you need to escape the percent symbol use two percent symbols. For example compare:

```
print "A big %age"
```

with

```
print "A big %%age"
```

Remember that the percent symbol is used for `printf` style formatting of variables.

Otherwise you could verbatim strings in your SQL:

```
db.prepare_v2( """SELECT pkid,name,source,servings FROM Recipes WHERE name like "%""" + res + """%"""", -1, out statement)
```

The next stage is then to read your results. Your code seems to be almost there, but you are missing `stmt.step()` and handling the return value of that call being either `ROW` or `DONE`. If you are not using the `Sqlite` namespace then it will be `Sqlite.ROW` and `Sqlite.DONE`. For a couple of examples of using the SQLite C API for SELECT statements see [Vala SQLITE Sample](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/SqliteSample) and [Sqlite C interface get single value result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637701/sqlite-c-interface-get-single-value-result) .